# Transpile forEach, map, filter and for of to length based for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webpack, micro-optimization

I have a WebGL project where every micro optimization matters. For readibility I use .forEach, .map, .filter and for of loops but I would like to transpile them to simple (reversed) length based for loops in my production code due to [performance reasons](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/655).
Could you please advise how to achieve that using Webpack? I am curious about best practices in this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, there are two Babel plugins available that do the job quite well.

- [@babel/plugin-transform-for-of](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-for-of) transpiles *for of* loops to index based loops
- [babel-plugin-loop-optimizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-loop-optimizer) transpiles .forEach, .every, .find, .map, .filter statements to index based for loops

In my configuration, I use Webpack and *ts-loader* to transpile TypeScript. To use these Babel plugins while keeping the ts-loader I chain the two loaders, thus Babel plugins will optimize the js code that comes out of ts-loader.

webpack.config.js:

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    use: [
        { // babel-loader runs second and receives output of ts-loader
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        { // ts-loader runs first
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                // ts-loader options
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of",
    "babel-plugin-loop-optimizer"
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, the second plugin is unmaintained and neither of them transpiles to reversed index based loops. One could publish a plugin that solves all of this in one place.